# Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{2-z-z^2}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

The problem is:

Find the Taylor expansion of $f(z):= \dfrac{1}{2-z-z^2}$ on the disc $|z| < 1$

So far I have used partial fractions to obtain $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{3}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-z} + \dfrac{1}{2+z}\right)$ which I then rewrite as $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{3}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-z} + \dfrac{1}{1-((-1)(1+z))}\right)$.

My problem is that we are told specifically to find the expansion on the disc $|z| < 1$, and whilst $\dfrac{1}{1-z}$ is valid for $|z| < 1$, $\dfrac{1}{1-((-1)(1+z))}$ is valid for $|1+z| < 1$. I am a guessing that we cannot just say $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{3}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n + (-1)^n(1+z)^n\right)$ but am not sure as my notes don't have any examples of this sort of difficulty.

Comment: Hint: $\frac 1{2+z}=\frac 12\cdot \frac 1{1+\frac z2}$

Comment: Just expand $1/(2-t)$ around $1/2$ and plug in $t=z+z^2$.

Comment: @JPi can you expand on this at all? I get the answer with Mark Bennets hint but following through with yours writing $1/(2-t)$ as $1/2$.$1/(1-(t/2))$ gives you something like $1/2$ of the sum of $((z+z^2)/2)^{n}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\ldots$ as infinitely descending geometric progression. And $\frac{1}{2+z}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-z/2)}=\ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{2-z-z^2}=\frac{ 1 }{ 2} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z-\frac{1}{2}z^2}=\frac {1}{2}\sum _{ n = 0 } ^ \infty(\frac { 1 } { 2 } (z+z^2))^{n}$.

Done.

Note that Since $|z|\lt 1 $, it follows that $|\frac {1}{2}(z + z ^ 2 )|\lt \frac {1}{2}(|z|+|z ^ 2|)\lt1$ so it is justified to use geometric series above.

Comment: This seems logical but am not fully sure if correct. Using my method with partial fractions and Mark Bennets hint gives the answer as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{6}z^{n}(2+(\frac{-1}{2})^{n})$, and I have checked this is correct. Can you work with your answer to get it into this form

Comment: Not sure.. Will try

Comment: Interestingly both of our expansions fail at $z=0$, unless you let $0^0=1$ guess that's the weird thing with infinite sums of zeros.

Comment: Your sum equates to $\frac{1}{3-3z}+\frac{1}{3+z/2}$

Comment: Sorry, $\frac { 1 } {3-3z}+\frac { 1 } {6+3z}$

Comment: Double checked yours and mine and they are equivalent!

Comment: Neither sum fails at $0$ since $0^{0} = 1$ as you said. $\frac{1}{3-3z} + \frac{1}{6+3z}$ is correct since this is equal to $\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{1}{2+z})$ which as I said in the question is the result you obtain by splitting $f$ into partial fractions.

Comment: Yeah I realised lol, seems they both work!